Vue 3 で対象のテンプレート内のドロップダウンで項目を選択するも、更新ボタンを押下しないとビュー側に表示されない
必要な情報は取得できており、更新ボタンを押下するとドロップダウンの出力結果が表示される。
リクエストを送って返ってきたものを表示させられるようにしたい。
ref1を使用する方法は試してみたが、変わらなかったです。
const selectEmployee = async (employeeId) => {
    console.log('Selected Employee ID:', employeeId);  

    if (!props.task || !props.task.id) {
        console.error('Task is undefined or has no id');
        return;
    }

    try {
        await assignTaskToEmployee(authToken, props.task.id, employeeId);
        emit('employeeAssigned', employeeId);
        emit('close');
        
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Failed to assign task:', error);
    }
};

